# Show/Hide Immediate next element Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm trying to show hide immediate next imput within the div, but it opens all the inputs 
I also tried

```
`$(this).next("input").show();` ( traversing )
```

nothing seems to work. 
Any help?

Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/526stLtg/1/

Comment: If possible using without Id Class on Input.

Comment: Always add relevent code here at SO

Comment: Satpal, please, add the code in the fiddle here. You should never link anything that can be deleted. SO should be as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** and for toggling visibility use **[`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-guest > button").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.add-guest input[type="text"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-guest">
  <b>Bride:</b> 
  <button id="bride">Add</button>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="Bride">
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="add-guest">
  <b>Groom:</b> 
  <button id="bride">Add</button>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="Bride">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` to refer to html element and using [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-guest > button").click(function() {
    $(this).text() === "Add" ? $(this).text("Remove") : $(this).text("Add");
    $(this).parent().find("input").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.add-guest input[type="text"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-guest">
  <b>Bride:</b> 
  <button id="bride">Add</button>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="Bride">
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="add-guest">
  <b>Groom:</b> 
  <button id="bride">Add</button>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="Bride">
</div>
```

Additionally you can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of [.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` to select the clicked button (the event trigger).

Then, if you look at your code, you'll see that the next element is a `<br/>`, and the next the `<input>` that you want to show. So, if you change:

```
$(".add-guest > input").show();
```

to

```
$(this).next().next().show();
```

It will work. You can think tha you can also use a selector to find the first sibling filtered by the selector, i.e.

```
$(this).next('input').show();
```

But this doesn't work. This checks if the sibling can be selected with the paseed selector. But you can use the `.nextAll('input')`, only because in this case there are only one sibling which can be seelcted like this. If not you could use this selector, and `.first()`

Your original code was selecting all inputs precede by elements with the `.add-guest` class, whic is not what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple input elemnts within div and you want to select first input element only then use `:first` pseudo-class

```
  $(this).parent().find("input:first").toggle();
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for Help. 
I completely forgot about Find() and too tight on project time. So posted here